# Very custom date format in momentjs

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, momentjs, kibana

I am working with kibana (elasticsearch dashboard) which allow to specify a date pattern to explain the index naming pattern.

For instance, default pattern is: `[logstash-]YYYY-MM-DD.HH`

I'd like to organize my index by block of hours, let's say by block of 4 hours. Indices would then be named `logstash-2014-02-25.00`, `logstash-2014-02-25.04`, `logstash-2014-02-25.08`, …

Is there any way to get such format with momentjs ? I am dreaming of `[logstash-]YYYY-MM-DD.{HH%4}`
but the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format) does not explain such thing (how weird).

Comment: Just adjust the hours with the Date API before you format it.

Comment: I'd have to modify kibana source code to do that, would'nt I ? I'd like to avoid that if possible unless necessary.

Comment: How do the dates get into the system in the first place?

Comment: it is a value given by moment(start)

Comment: it seems impossible but there might be workaround using language customization

Comment: Maybe, but (knowing little about kibana) it seems like getting the dates to be in the right form from the start would make things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to do it with formatting primitives.

However, I found we can override some of the language-dependant formatter such as meridiem formatter.
A solution would then be to insert somewhere (in kibana conf file for example):

```
moment.lang('fourHourblocks', {
  meridiem: function(hour, minute, isLowercase) {
    hourBlock = Math.floor(hour / 4).toString();
    if (hourBlock.length < 2) hourBlock = "0" + hourBlock;
    return hourBlock;
  }
}
```

then I can set the pattern to `[logstash-]YYYY-MM-DD.A`.

This is kind of hacky so I am still opened to other solutions